# Memory issue or connection issue with SPRING REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

We have a RESTful Spring web services on Java 7 hosted on Apache Tomcat8.

The Request-response takes less than a second usually.

But sometimes it takes 20 to 40 seconds (say 1 out of 10 hits)

Whenever I restart the server, I do not notice this for quite some time.

Is it a connection pooling issue or memory issue. Any ideas on how to diagnose this?

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Datasource:

[image]

JDBC template config:

[image]

I am extending this class in all my Dao and call the template like below.

```
super.jdbcTemplate.query(<query and params here>)
```

After making many changes still, there is no improvement. I have to mention one more thing here. We save images as blob to db. Will that cause any problem at all?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to setup some JMX monitoring to check if there is indeed mis-memory usage.

Comment: You can use logger for recognize where the problem occur. Please call the logger before and after creation of your bean and by invoke of datasource.
You should set the higher level in the global configuration of Tomcat not in the application configuration. If you use java.util.logging set the level to FINEST or ALL. You should be able to see more information by deployment of your web-application and application work especially the bean creation time and delay of calls.